# QFutureWatcher doesn't emit signals as expected

Tags: c++, qt, concurrency, future

I can't get QFutureWatcher to emit any signals when watching a future.
The simple snippet seen below prints `Result: 1` as expected but neither of the two connected lambdas are ever called.
What am I missing here?

```
#include <QtDebug>
#include <QtConcurrent>

int main() {
    auto futureWatcher = new QFutureWatcher<int>{};

    QObject::connect(futureWatcher, &QFutureWatcher<int>::resultReadyAt, [](int index) {
        qInfo() << "Result ready"; 
    });
    QObject::connect(futureWatcher, &QFutureWatcher<int>::finished, []() {
        qInfo() << "Future finished"; 
    });

    QFuture<int> future = QtConcurrent::run([](QPromise<int>& promise) {promise.addResult(1);});
    futureWatcher->setFuture(future);

    auto results = future.results();
    for (auto result : results) {
        qInfo() << "Result:" << result;
    }
}
```

Comment: For signals to fire, the thread that expects to receive a signal needs to run an event loop; e.g. via `QApplication::exec()`. Yours instead blocks on `future.results()`

Comment: How did I miss that? Thank you very much, solved!